# Suggested Edits Audits generate slowly

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, review-audits

I noticed something, after reviewing many suggested edits audits in the past few months. The suggested edit audits generate slowly, so it is pretty easy to determine if a suggested edit is an audit. In suggested edits, the system generate audits using a system, but it takes a lot longer time to show up then the normal reviews. Could this be improved?

Comment: This is true of all audits in review. I guess they are generated as needed, causing a noticeable wait time on modern connections. I am sure this is a duplicate but I can't find it

Comment: Kudos to you for noticing it is an audit ... You'll be amazed how many still fail these despite all the signals ....

Comment: @rene I am very careful in reviewing, and haven’t failed for months.